# PHP add and times this number?

Tags: php

I am trying to +5 and then *10 on something selected from the database.

BTW: *$stats['Level'] = 1*

So here's my code.

```
<?php echo intval(floor($stats['Level'] + 5 * 10)); ?>
```

What am I doing wrong? It's showing as 51, not 60. Why's that?

Answer (score 5):

[Order of operations](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

Multiplication is before addition.  Try this instead:

```
echo intval(floor(($stats['Level'] + 5) * 10))
```

Answer (score 3):

Order of operations. Multiplication always comes before addition. You'll need to use parenthesis to overcome that as they have a higher presidence.

```
<?php echo intval(floor(($stats['Level'] + 5) * 10)); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Order of operations states that multiplication always comes before addition so your code should look like this:

```
echo intval(floor(($stats['Level'] + 5) * 10))
```